# What fraction of U.S. voters actually do due diligence in voting for positions such as comptrollers?

Tags: united-states, voter-turnout

For instance, the New York City Comptroller is elected. I’m honestly surprised that even such positions involve public elections.

Is there data on what fraction of voters actually participate to vote for such positions? Even more importantly, what fraction of voters actually look at the records of contenders to make *informed* votes?

Comment: That's one reason political parties exist.

Comment: The first question is pretty easy to answer (you're just asking for turnout), but it's very broad – the answer will vary for every different minor position and city or state. The second is much harder to answer and I suspect there might not be reliable data for it (how do you measure whether someone is informed about something?)

Comment: @divibisan I understand this is a difficult question, but one can perhaps run surveys to see whether voters are knowledgable about the people (e.g. comptrollers) they are voting for.

Comment: @Relaxed Then we might as well change the system to have people just voting for political parties who then pick the comptrollers. (Of course, on some level this is what happens).

Comment: @JLi That's true, which is why I didn't vote to close. You might want to focus on just one of these questions, preferably the second, since it's more interesting

Comment: @divibisan I doubt you could find "due diligence" data on even the Presidential election, let alone lower level positions.

Comment: How do you even objectively define "due diligence" and "informed"?  Those are fundamentally subjective judgments in the realm of politics.

Comment: In many cases, even if you somehow manage rigorous definitions for "informed" and "due diligence", they will be impossible to achieve and so won't really be fair.  There just isn't much publicly accessible information available about politicians records below the national level.  Unless he's been involved in a huge scandal, it's going to be tough to find many articles about your local comptroller.

Comment: @Relaxed Political theory and poly sci research generally supports this contention. One of the better sources are empirical studies of coattails in Presidential election years in lower political offices (which are very substantial for partisan down ticket races, on average). And, usually partisan affiliation produces with very little effort the same outcome that details due diligence would (there are also studies about that).

Comment: I seem to follow politics closer than most, and I have no idea what plans a comptroller candidate has, therefore I would presume reasoned evaluations to be quite low. The main reason that margins differ from other party candidates in such races is candidate scandals, which is particular knowledge, but isn't the quite same as evaluating positions.